# Added Word Doc to CVS - became corrupt

Tags: ms-word, cvs, docx, corrupt

I'm using CVSNT.  I added a Microsoft 2007 docx file "as text" to the repository. After committing and before updating I tried to open the file again but was unable to. It said it was corrupt.

I tried using the office word doc recovery and that was unable to recover the document.

From what I understand I should've added the word doc as a binary file instead of text. My mistake.

Unfortunately my word doc is still corrupt. Is there anyway to get that back?

Comment: This belongs on SuperUser.com since it's not programming related

Answer (score 1):

The file is lost. :(  Looking at an older version of the document, the filesize is 40k.  The file stored in cvs is 1k.  Too much info loss to be recovered.

Note to self. Use git.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no real way.  Adding as text instructs CVS to manage the line endings, CVS will have played with \r and \n such that it is unrecoverable.

Answer (score 0):

CVS probably attempted to change line endings. If you change CR/LF to LF inside, the problem may be fixed, or you may have gotten closer to a situation where the recovery tool works.